# How to use an event on svg?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to start a simple animation on an svg element in HTML, but the effect doesn't work.

I want to add this:

```
.arrow-behind {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
         transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.arrow-front {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15px);
         transform: translateY(15px);
 }
```

to this,

HTML:

```
   <div class="content">
      <p>Hover me !</p>
      <svg id="more-arrows">
        <polygon  points="37.6,64 0,36.1 5.1,32.8 37.6,56.8 70.4,32.8 75.5,36.1 "/>
        <polygon  points="37.6,64 0,36.1 5.1,32.8 37.6,56.8 70.4,32.8 75.5,36.1 "/>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#more-arrows {
  width: 75px;
  height: 85px;
}

 #more-arrows polygon {
  fill: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
```

with this,

JS:

```
clicked = document.getElementById("more-arrows");

clicked.addEventListener("click", opened)

function opened() {
  addclass = document.getElementsByClassName("polygon")
  addclass.setAttribute("class", "arrow-behind");
  addclass.setAttribute("class", "arrow-front");
}
```

Comment: And how are you loading that JS? Because that detail is _critically important_ if you have questions about JS that needs to work with DOM elements. Are you using `<script src="myfile.js" async defer></script>`? Also note that none of your CSS needs those vendor prefixes.

Comment: It's in the body tag.

Comment: which you're not showing, so again: [how are you loading your JS](/help/how-to-ask). Is it inline? Is it a script element? Is it somewhere in the body? Is it at the end? (It's 2021 so you really want to put it in the `<head>` as script element with `async` and `defer` attributes, not in the body. That's what we used to have to do before `defer` existed)

Comment: Use `getElementsByTagName` instead because the polygons do not have a class, making the `getElementsByClassName` collection empty. Or give them the class and also change the classes in the `opened` function.

Comment: Thanks, it works now!